# Who is videsktop in my GA stats?

Tags: google-analytics

I am looking at the traffic on my site via GA and there is one entry at the top of my list called "videsktop". How do I figure out who or what that is? I tried clicking on it, but it just takes me deeper into an analysis. I did a search on it, and couldn't find anything that made sense. See below please.[image]

Comment: I am not sure where you are seeing this. Can you post an image to help us? You can black-out parts of the image to make it more anonymous.

Comment: Okay, done. What do you think?

Comment: I see this once I click on "All Referrals"

Comment: I see http://www.videsktop.com/. It is also possible that this is a bogus referrer. Referrers are often faked. Have you applied for a job lately, sent resumes, or posted a resume online?

Answer (score 1):

viDestktop is a company that sells human resources software.   It would appear that there is an instance of their software that links to your site and is installed on an intranet. That software may have a host name of `videsktop.example.com` but because it is in-house, the users of the software can access it just by `http://videsktop` in their browsers.

When they click on the link from it to your site, your site only sees the `videsktop` portion of the host name.

You could validate this further by:

- Clicking on videsktop in Google Analytics and seeing the the URL paths from the clicks.  This might give you further indication of which of viDesktop's web apps are linking to you
- Looking further down the referrer list for `videsktop.example.com`  -- maybe somebody accessed it with a full host name in the URL.

Comment: It appears that the software scrubs the websites of applicants. I cannot swear by this, but that is the impression I got. Many HR personnel will research a resume they receive or have in a database without your actually applying for a job only supplying a resume or had sometime in the past. This can still happen as HR personnel share data. Some companies will fully vet an individual who has never contacted the company or intended to. These are usually for executive positions where passive candidates are considered desirable.